# Android gradle 'installDebug' task stopped working after update

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Task installDevDebug stopped working after updating gradle plugin from 
2.1.3 to 2.3.3

```
./gradlew installDevDebug
...
Unable to install 
/Users/user/Android/MyApp/app/build/outputs/apk/App-1.34.0-dev-
debug-unaligned.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:96)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:904)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:136)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
```

build.gradle

```
...
buildscript {
    ext.gradle_plugin_version = '2.3.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

...
    productFlavors {
        prod {
        }
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 21
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what changed in gradle plugin, and how to fix this issue?
Maybe problem is with build flavors?
Thank you.

Comment: Does clean build and restarting the IDE fix it?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Check if [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9498) helps you. Although it is ReactNative related, but might be useful.

Comment: @Sufian thanks for sharing, but i'm already know about this issue. It doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to specify this maven repository at the same time I upgraded my Intellij to 2017.2 (which is what forced that gradle plugin upgrade upon me).

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```